# Why can't I disconnect from a wireless network?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I'm trying to disconnect from a wireless network, but whenever I click "Disconnect", nothing happens. See this video:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqDrJjU6PMs

I've tried to disable it, and re-enable it but this doesn't work. I've also tried pressing the button on the laptop and this didn't work either.

Comment: Does that happen when you try to click anything else? Has it been happening for long?

Comment: What type of connection is it, and what type of connection is the one above?

Comment: Looks almost like a stuck mouse button or keyboard key.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the *Connect automatically when this network is in range* checkbox *UNCHECKED* in the properties of this connection. Open the *Network and Sharing Center > Manage wireless networks*, then select the network and right click to get the properties.

[image]

You could removing the network from your wireless networks list if you open the *Network and Sharing Center > Manage wireless networks*, then select the network and click on *Remove*.
You could also try deleting the network...

[image]

Comment: I can't uncheck the connect automatically box  because it says only the administrator can change it. Although i am an administrator, shouldn't there be a shield next to it and i have to allow the action through UAC?

Comment: You might try turning off UAC.  [link] (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off)

Comment: Also, is it possible that you have another wireless manager installed for your wireless adapter?  Have you tried creating a new user on the system?  With the other user, are you able to disconnect from the wireless network?  Did you try updating the drivers for your wireless adapter?